# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate crashes the computer if running as administrator

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My computer crashes and the screen freezes when I run Visual Studio 2010 ultimate as administrator.

I have Visual Assist X 10.7 installed only. I'm using Windows 8 Pro x64.

Comment: Hi TariqoO! I hope by "vs assist 10.7" you meant Visual Assist X. If that's not the case feel free to [edit] your question and fix that part.

Comment: i forgeted write the X :)

Comment: create a crashdump, open it with WinDbg and run **!analyze -v**. What do you see?

Comment: where's windbg ? and i cant make crashdump because the screen freeze so i cant see what im doing

Comment: do you get a BSOD?

Comment: no i got screen freeze only